# How to create a full glass, round frame form in c#?

Tags: c#, forms, aero-glass

Here's how I want the form to look like:
[image]

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MARGINS
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Right;
        public int Top;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
    public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMargins);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MARGINS marg = new MARGINS() { Left = -1, Right = -1, Top = -1, Bottom = -1 };
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, ref marg);
    }
```

That does make my form all transparent, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the round corners.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make custom shaped forms using default forms. It should be possible by overriding a lot of classes, which is really a pain. Check out http://telerik.com/ controls. They provide you with a custom form control, any shape you want.

Comment: Have you tried making the form rounded first and then applying the glass effect?

Comment: Which round corners are you referring to? If you're talking about the edges of the window frame, they should already be rounded. Could you post a screenshot of what your form looks like at the moment?